# Spring Boot - Apache Kafka Client compatibility

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I cannot get Spring-Kafka to work with Kafka client versions 1.x. I get the below error when I work with higher kafka clients (> 2)

> [Consumer clientId=adapter1-0, groupId=xxxx] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

However the code seems to work with Kafka client version 1.1.

I cannot find out if it is Spring issue or KAfka client version issue

Comment: Well, you could remove Spring and write a plain Consumer using both versions in order to debug and isolate the issue

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. It was an issue with Spring Boot - Spring Kafka and Kafka client compatibility. The kafka endpoint was in 1.1 version. So I had to use older verison of Spring boot and spring kafka client (version 2.0.7)